# How to select the values in my dataframe which has logical operator "<" (less than), divide them by two, and convert all as.numeric

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with character-type columns. I need to take each value as a string, find out if there is a logical operator exist. If it is TRUE, then divide it by two and there this numeric value. If there is NO logical operator, just put back here a number. At the end I would want to have all "numeric" values dataframe. 
[This dataframe](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1v6WuIetoZJvL4F4XYqCamBtBzvte1qjX)

```
1   <0.0001 5.89    34.6    0.044   1.14    <1  1.77    <1  19.2    310 20.2    2.94    1.38    31.9    0.94    0.115   5.2 2.38    38.4    0.078
2   <0.0001 5.77    40.7    0.042   1.25    <1  1.67    <1  20.6    260 19.5    3.14    1.51    30.2    1.04    0.098   27.7    2.54    39.4    0.07
3   <0.0001 6.77    44.3    0.039   1.38    <1  1.62    <1  21.3    180 16.9    3.79    1.65    26.8    1.26    0.076   2.6 2.63    43.4    0.63
```

Comment: What have you tried? This should be straight-forward with `lapply`, `grepl`, `gsub`, and `as.numeric`.

Comment: I'm just studying to make this. That's what I'm trying to do with your help.. ))

Comment: Thanx a lot! This is working. I 'm going to continue scratching R.... ! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To demonstrate, I downloaded your data and truncated it significantly for the purposes of this Q/A.

```r
dat <- read.table(header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, text = "
U   Th  Na  Ca  Fe  Rb  Sr  
<0.7    7.7 <0.1    <0.4    2.5 <0.001  <150    
<0.7    6.5 <0.1    <0.4    2.4 <0.001  <150    
<0.7    5.8 <0.1    <0.4    2.9 <0.001  <150    
<0.7    7.5 <0.1    <0.4    2.8 <0.001  <150    
<0.7    7.6 <0.1    <0.4    3.2 <0.001  <150    
<0.7    6.8 0.89    <0.4    4   0.0049  <150    
")

myfun <- function(x, ineq = c("<", ">", "=", "<=", ">=")) {
  ptn <- paste0("^(", paste(ineq, collapse = "|"), ")") # "^(<|>|=|<=|>=)"
  hasineq <- grepl(ptn, x)
  x <- gsub(ptn, "", x)
  x <- as.numeric(x)
  x[hasineq] <- x[hasineq] / 2
  x
}

# the use of dat[] here is to preserve its class as 'data.frame'
dat[] <- lapply(dat, myfun)
dat
#      U  Th   Na  Ca  Fe     Rb Sr
# 1 0.35 7.7 0.05 0.2 2.5 0.0005 75
# 2 0.35 6.5 0.05 0.2 2.4 0.0005 75
# 3 0.35 5.8 0.05 0.2 2.9 0.0005 75
# 4 0.35 7.5 0.05 0.2 2.8 0.0005 75
# 5 0.35 7.6 0.05 0.2 3.2 0.0005 75
# 6 0.35 6.8 0.89 0.2 4.0 0.0049 75
```